# How can I skip checking a particular input field?

Tags: jquery

I am using the selector :input to check if all the fields have text in them, which works, but I now need it to skip one specific input field while checking? 
This code below is checking all of the fields.

```
var emptyTextBoxes = $('input:text').filter(function () {
    return !$(this).is(':hidden') && this.value === "" ;
});
```

Comment: An input cannot have an element in it. Please clarify.

Comment: What are you trying to remove? You can use the `:not` selector to remove elements from a jQuery selection string (or the `.not()` method as well.)

Comment: I just want to check all the boxes minus one specific box, should it be removed--or is there another way?

Comment: I don't see the `:input` selector being used in your code at all.

Comment: Are you asking for checking all input fields except that particular one or are you trying to remove a particular input field? Please edit and question and clarify your intentions

Comment: @Huangism  I am currently checking all input fields, but want it to skip checking one specific field

Comment: @Vtienne doesn't `$('input:text').not("#currentUPCAmount")` work? http://api.jquery.com/not/ `$('input:text').not("#currentUPCAmount").filter(f...`

Comment: @Huangism that works.. trying to give you the green check but no option

Comment: @Vtienne make a comment if the ID isn't correct don't attempt to update the answer's code. In this case, it really makes no difference since your question does not include the ID

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To skip that particular input use `.not()` This will remove `#currentUPCAmount` from `$('input:text')`

```
$('input:text').not("#currentUPCAmount")
```

Documentation and examples can be found http://api.jquery.com/not/

So your final line will look like

```
var emptyTextBoxes = $('input:text').not("#currentUPCAmount").filter(function () {
    return !$(this).is(':hidden') && this.value === "" ;
});
```